# Dealing with controllers and data models

Tags: angularjs, model, controller

I know that the best practice is to make controllers as thin as possible. But is it possible for a controller to be too thin? For example, the code below shows three cases:

I know that case #1 is the worst case. But is case #3 preferable to case #2?

I used a hard-coded "Hello World" to simplify. In reality there would be business logic that returns a message.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

// model is inside controller (worst case)
app.controller('controller1', function() {
  this.message = 'Hello World';
});

// template accesses model thru controller. (getting thinner)
app.controller('controller2', function(model) {
  this.message = model.getMessage();
});


// controller pass model to template. (ultra thin)
app.controller('controller3', function(model) {
  this.model = model;
});



app.factory('model', function() {
  return {
    getMessage: function() {
      return 'Hello World'
    }
  }

});
```

And the HTML...

```
    <body>
      <div ng-controller='controller1 as vm1'>{{vm1.message}}</div>
      <div ng-controller='controller2 as vm2'>{{vm2.message}}</div>
      <div ng-controller='controller3 as vm3'>{{vm3.model.getMessage()}}   </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case where your model return static text ther is no difference.

But imagine a classic dataservice model that make a call to an api.

Is preferable to resolve the promise from the http call inside controller so you can manage the errors. And this point to your case #2.

Hope this help clarify the situation

Comment: But what about handling just basic state information? Stuff like current selections on the page. Seems more convenient to let the controller just hookup the view and model together (as in case 3), and let the view access it directly. (Although, something just feels wrong about that to me - it's seems to totally diminish the role of a controller)

Comment: There is no particular problem until the model return data that you have to modify in the view in order to display "something" (the data, an error, hide a div ex) if you have to put logic in the view that's a problem.  If your model are so specialized that every single data returned is managed by a simple view there is no problem in your approach.  Remember to always return object to avoid problem with data binding